# How well can Node.js perform real-time and VOD and WebCam streaming?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, live-streaming, broadcasting

I am developing a system included a realtime chat with nodejs+socketio+redis.But beside this i want to add webcam streaming.It is my first time to build such a project (webcam streaming) so i have no idea what exactly i need . i am totally blocked and confused while searching for a solid guide.
*A small description about project: 
-User log in and then it can open a webcam broadcast and other users can join in its room and only can watch and listen . I want to use it in my project as Doctor-Patient system ,that if a doctor broadcast some patients can type their own questions in the chat and doctor can answer in the webcam broadcast.*
So my quesions are ;

- What kind of server do i need?
- Can i handle streaming with nodejs?
- Is it better to just use Wowza or any other solutions/suggestions?

I really need help in this to be clear in my head.I will be really appreciated.Thanks.